# Get value from RestSharp response headers

Tags: http-headers, response, restsharp

I'm hoping someone can help with an issue I'm having with RestSharp. It's all working; I'm getting my reply using the following code:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://mybaseuri.com");
var request = new RestRequest("service/{id}", Method.GET);
request.AddUrlSegment("id", id);
    
// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I'd like to get a value from the response headers along the lines of:

```
string userId = response.Headers["userId"]
```

I can't find any examples online, can anyone help get a value from the `response.Headers` object which is of type `IList<parameter>`?

I'm not looking to iterate the entire collection, just extract a single value by name.

Answer (score 23):

As I was wondering myself how to do the same, I find out the following solution with the help of this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) about `IList<T>`:

```
string userId = response.Headers.ToList()
    .Find(x => x.Name == "userId")
    .Value.ToString();
```

I need to confess I'm fond of playing in Visual Studio with ***Immediate Window*** or ***Quick Watch*** to dig a bit and know what kind of element Type I'm dealing with:

```
response.Headers[0]
```

> {userId=1024}
>
> Name: "userId"
>
> **Type: HttpHeader**
>
> Value: "1024"

Comment: What if the header doesn't exist? this causes a null reference exception.

Answer (score 7):

Using LINQ:

```
string userId = response.Headers
    .Where(x => x.Name == "userId")
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This requires no knowledge of the index of the element, and deals with the scenario where the header does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

It's not difficult with Linq:

```
if( response.Headers.Any(t=>t.Headers == "Location"))
{
    string location = 
    response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Name == "Location").Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the index of "userId" then you can do the following:

```
string userId = response.Headers.ElementAt(indexOfUserId).Value.ToString();
```