# How get the response header with RESTSharp?

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I'm developing a program who call an API, all works fine but I have to recover  some information which are on the response header, how can I recover the information?

I have tried something like : `string h = response.Headers;` but it doesn't work.

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://xxxx.com/");

        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password");


        var request = new RestRequest("xx/xx/xx", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var xml_text = response.Content;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from RestSharp response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338511/get-value-from-restsharp-response-headers)

Comment: I have all ready saw this post but it doesn't help me !

Comment: @ALDZAFE where in YOUR code are you trying to access the headers? Also, the procedure in that example clearly lays out how to get the headers list and search for a particular header by name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that response headers in RestSharp are returned as a collection (`IList`) so declaring `h` as a string won't work. See the source [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/HttpResponse.cs). You might want to try and cast the value to a string like this:

```
foreach (var h in response.Headers)
{
  h.ToString();
}
```

If you know name of the header you're looking for, you can use a bit of LINQ like what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164551/6174904) :

```
string userId = response.Headers
    .Where(x => x.Name == "userId")
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I tried with `response.Headers.ToString();` and the result is `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[RestSharp.Parameter]` and that's not what I execpt. I don't know the name of the header ...

Comment: Because the headers are returned as a collection, you'll probably have to do a `foreach` to get to the values in the headers. I updated the answer.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I avoided the LINQ with a simple IF...THEN. Declare the variable outside, then 'if (h.ToString().StartsWith("userId")  )
                        { USERId = h.ToString(); }'

Comment: @Edward why avoid the LINQ expression though? It's much cleaner and more concise, and doesn't pollute scope with potentially useless variables.